# laravel does not do update in the bank

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

the following error is occurring when trying to perform update on a specific field in the database

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'or
>     der=5 WHERE id=34;

```
\DB::table('action')
             ->where('id','=','34' )
             ->update(array('order'=>'5'));
```

I am try `order`, '`order`', "`order`","order".

Comment: `order` is a [reserved word in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). I'd really suggest renaming the column to something else, or use a raw query where you can use the backticks.

Comment: @aynber Laravel should already handle escaping all table names natively (unless `DB::raw()` is being used). I'm more suspicious about the space in OP's `or der=5` output and wonder if they have a funky character somewhere.

Comment: @ceejayoz I noticed that too. I was just trying to decide if that was valid or if it was a copy error. Looking at the edit, there's a line break there. *shrug*